# numpy 2D arrays as pandas elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How could I use numpy 2d arrays as pandas row-column elements properly?

I tried some easy examples, but when I save and load the database the format of the array changes and I can't access the indexes of the array (but I can access the element in general).

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['array','A','B'])
v = np.zeros((2,2))
df.loc[0,'array'] = v
df.loc[0,'A'] = 'some'
df.loc[0,'B'] = 'other'
df.to_csv('experiment.csv',index=False)
```

Things I tried to read numpy array of element `0`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('experiment.csv')

new_v1 = df.loc[0,'array']
print(new_v1[0,1])

new_v2 = np.array(df.loc[0,'array'])
print(new_v2[0,1])

new_v3 = df.loc[0,'array'].item()
print(new_v3[0,1])
```

But it shows the following errors:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'item'
```

How can I use numpy arrays for each element? Is it possible?

**SOLUTIONS**

As *ALollz* said, I didn't need to be in human readable format, so I used pickle format. This way is straight save, load and use the same as a python variable.

Another option is using another separator (*mdk*'s solution). But from what I understand, you have to convert the array to string and back from string plus reshaping the array if it is more than one dimension (using `reshape`).

Comment: Save your file as a .pkl  `df.to_pickle('experiment.pkl')` and then you can load it with `pd.read_pickle()`. When you save it as a csv you lose all information about it being an array.

Comment: If it has to be human readable, you can also go with json format. As ALollz mentions, csv is not the right file format in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original DataFrame looks like this:

```
                      array     A      B
 0  [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]  some  other
```

The array contains 3 times ",", and you are using `df.to_csv('experiment.csv',index=False)` with the standard separator "," (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).

Try using another separator, e.g. `df.to_csv('experiment.csv', sep=';',index=False)` and `df = pd.read_csv('experiment.csv', sep=';')`.

Your DataFrame looks now like this:

```
                    array     A      B
0  [[0. 0.]\r\n [0. 0.]]  some  other
```

After import your array is no longer an array, but a string.
Use [numpy.fromstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) to convert the array string back to a numpy array.